# mongo db How to group data like this?

Tags: mongodb

Now i get this table(it can't be more than two kinds of {A,B,C} to appear in the same data at the same time.):

```
{_id:1,A:a}
{_id:2,B:b}
{_id:3,C:a}
{_id:4,A:a}
{_id:5,A:b}
{_id:6,A:c}
{_id:7,C:a}
```

How to get this result?

```
a:4
b:2
c:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get this result with mongodb aggregation framework,

first, you'll need to add all the value in a single field, and the perform a **`$group`** on that field:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    "$project": {
        "v": ["$A", "$B", "$C"]
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$v"
}, {
    "$match": {
        "v": {
            "$ne": null
        }
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$v",
        "count": {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
}])
```

result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "c",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "b",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "a",
    "count": 4
  }
]
```

you can try it here: [mongoplayground.net/p/rGHUPWsw2ee](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rGHUPWsw2ee)

Comment: Thanks,very useful.

Comment: `db.collection.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: null, values_A: {$push: '$A'}, values_B: {$push: '$B'}, values_C: {$push: '$C'}}},
    {$project: {values: {$concatArrays: ['$values_A', '$values_B', '$values_C']}}},
    {$unwind: '$values'},
    {$group: {_id: '$values', total: {$sum: 1}}}
])` I used $push and $concatArrays, but $concatArrays only supported from MongoDB 3.2. If you're using older verion, follow the answer.

Comment: @felix,@TrungLeNguyenNhat,How about MongoDB 2.6?

Comment: @Lamyee don't use MongoDB 2.6, it's been deprecated for more than 3 years... You should run at least MongoDB 3.2